# Can not use querymen with typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

I am using `"querymen"` library to parse the query string to `mongodb` | `mongoose` query and I am writing my code in `TypeScript`

```
import { middleware as query } from 'querymen';
 // then the route .
xRouter.get('/', query(), ...... );
```

but always giving me error :

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'querymen'. '/Users/meroo/Desktop/erp-next/erpnext/node_modules/querymen/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/querymen` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'querymen';`
```

I tried many ways to solve that issue but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no types available for that lib, you're going to need to write it yourself by creating a `d.ts` file that contains `declare module 'querymen';`